# Use Order in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

I have a table called DUAL in access.

**My Query is:**

```
select * from 
(select val(1) as NO from dual
union all
select val(3) as NO from dual
union all
select val(2) as NO from dual) a
order by No
```

**Result :**

```
NO
2
3
1
```

Why **`Order By No`** not running well?

**the results I want is**

```
NO
1
2
3
```

Thank you very much

Comment: Remove all the `val()` calls. Does that change anything?

Comment: Yes, I do it. but not change anything

Comment: The results you say you're getting do not match what I get when I use the same SQL statement. Not sure how to help you when I can't reproduce the problem and when it makes no logical sense for you to get those results.

Comment: Is that actual data? If not, edit question to post sample of actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess NO is a reserved word, and the outer query is not needed, thus:

```
select val(1) as [NO] from dual
union all
select val(3) as [NO] from dual
union all
select val(2) as [NO] from dual
order by [NO]
```

Comment: or `ORDER BY 1`